# Identify which user or process initiated normal shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, logs

I'd like to identify why (who, what) showdown my MacBook Pro while it was left unattended.  Some unsaved work was lost.  It is fairly likely that a careless admin script was run through some automated means by my company. No one initiated shutdown through the GUI or keyboard. I'd like to discover more so that I can start a conversation with IT.  (I have admin privaleges on my own laptop, and so does employer.) MacOS 10.14.6

```
$ log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 24h
Filtering the log data using "composedMessage CONTAINS "Previous shutdown cause""

Timestamp        Thread   Type     Activity    PID  TTL  
2020-10-15 19:11 0xcf     Default  0x0         0    0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Code 5 means:

> Correct Shut Down.    Shutdown was initiated normally, from the macOS Shut Down menu or other shutdown command such as /sbin/shutdown. This does not indicate an issue with your system.

```
$ last
myusername  ttys003                   Fri Oct 16 06:38   still logged in
myusername  ttys002                   Thu Oct 15 19:14   still logged in
myusername  ttys001                   Thu Oct 15 19:14   still logged in
myusername  ttys000                   Thu Oct 15 19:14   still logged in
myusername  console                   Thu Oct 15 19:13   still logged in
reboot    ~                         Thu Oct 15 19:11 
myusername  ttys002                   Wed Oct 14 09:44 - crash (1+09:27)
```

> ```
> The pseudo-user reboot logs in at reboots of the system, thus ``last
> reboot'' will give an indication of mean time between reboot.
> ```

Comment: "*It is fairly likely that a careless admin script was run through some automated means by my company.*"  How do you know this?  Does your IT department manage your MacBook with a particular tool?  Do they have scripts installed? How and did you validate this? Now, you said you left your Mac unattended.  Did you *lock it* or was your desktop open?

Comment: The screen was locked and I'm the only one home.  heh heh.  Also this happens perhaps a few times a year which is obnoxious.

Comment: "_It is fairly likely that a careless admin script was run through some automated means by my company._"   I don't know that for a fact.  IT does have ability to push updates through some background infrastructure largely out of sight.  I don't know what they use. Since no one had physical access to the laptop and I'm sure I did not initiate a normal shutdown, I conclude some other actor on my system did.  That's not crazy to install some security update or policy patch, etc. It is obnoxious to do the shutdown without the real user (me) in the loop.

Comment: Also, looking at the logs, a reboot command was issued - this could have been from an applied update (automatically).  There are instances (issues) where a reboot won't actually reboot, but shutdown instead.  It's unlikely there's an "actor" involved here as shutting down the computer is about the least productive thing both well and mal-intentioned people can do as the system is no longer available to be worked upon.

Comment: Yes, I tend to agree some sort of script was run.  But what script? what process? what user?  This was a rare case where I was connected to the Company VPN in the evening while the laptop was on its own.  I think my overall question and description is still correctly worded and specific.  A typical MacOS update would have prompted me and would not have initiated a reboot without my consent.